# how to disable radio button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

if I give only disable property its not working how to make radio button disable

```
import React from "react";
const App = () => {
      let platformData = ["And", "win", "ios"];
      let platform = "platform";
    
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            type="radio"
            disabled
            name="Platform"
            id="Platform"
            radioList={platformData}
            radioName={platform}
          />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? It gets disabled actually but what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Here is the working code sandbox of your actual code: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-elion-72t97?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what is `radioName` and `radioList` on an `input` element?

Comment: normally we are doing input type radio but in this case we have to access the obj so in disable property if I want to put its not working

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution to this problem you need to pass in disabled={true} or you could do something like this

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  let platformData = ["And", "win", "ios"];
  let platform = "platform";
  let disabled = true;

  if (platform) // or any other kind of condition
      disabled = false;

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        disabled={disabled}
        name="Platform"
        id="Platform"
        radioList={platformData}
        radioName={platform}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```